# Node + Flask server Docker containers not able to communicate over same network

Tags: python, node.js, docker, flask

I have 2 microservices that I'm dockerizing via docker-compose. Once my node service pings my python service, I get a connection refused.

I can ping both services independently via Postman and everything looks fine. It seems the container-to-container networking is what I'm having issues with. The node server is pinging a request via `Axios` like so:

```js
    const res = await axios.get('bot:9000/test')
```

and the server code on the Python side looks like:

```py
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
async def tester():
    return jsonify(data='hi'), 200
```

## Compose File

```
version: '3'
services:
  bot:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./app-bot
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./app-bot:/app
    environment: 
      - TELEGRAM_API_KEY=xxxx
      - BOT_PORT=4040
  channel-scraper:
    restart: always
    image: quart-app
    environment:
      - QUART_APP=api
    build:
      context: ./app-channelscrape/server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    env_file:
    - .env
```

## Node Docker File

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

## Flask Docker File

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN adduser -D quart
WORKDIR /home/quart

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --upgrade && \
  chown -R quart:quart ./

COPY ./ /home/quart/
USER quart

CMD ["quart", "run", "-h", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "9000"]
```

Comment: It looks like you're making the request to `bot` as a host name, but from the bot service itself; do you mean to call `http://channel-scraper:9000` to reach the other service?

Comment: @DavidMaze yup that was indeed the issue. :) Noticed this last night . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the containers you want to talk to each other are on the same network. 
add it this code in the end of your docker-compose file

```
networks:
  some-net:
    driver: bridge
```

And then add this like in which service that you want to be in the this network

```
    networks:
      - some-net
```

Your code will be like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  bot:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./app-bot
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./app-bot:/app
    environment: 
      - TELEGRAM_API_KEY=xxxx
      - BOT_PORT=4040
    networks:
      - some-net
  channel-scraper:
    restart: always
    image: quart-app
    environment:
      - QUART_APP=api
    build:
      context: ./app-channelscrape/server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - some-net

networks:
  some-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Getting the same issue. I tried this before as well.

Comment: nvm.. silly mistake I was pinging the wrong service. Thanks!

Comment: Compose automatically provides a network named `default` and this shouldn't be necessary.  Further details are in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.